# Variable substitution in subprocess call

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to run this bash command using subprocess through some substitution.
server.txt has list of server name, this script has to run on multiple servers and output should be redirected to a file as in the bash command. Pls help.

BASH Command:

```
ssh server1 "cat /home/pxh07/python/list| tail -n +2"
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import commands
import sys
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
cmd = "cat /home/user1/python/list| tail -n +2 >  data.out"
SSH = "ssh "
fh = open('server.txt')
for server_name in fh:
  subprocess.call(SSH + server_name + cmd,shell=True)
fh.close()
```

Comment: what you want ?

Comment: `server_name + cmd` is probably creating the string without space between server name and command. Check the command you're sending. also use `subprocess` with a list of args, not a command string, or even `paramiko` which is able to run ssh

Comment: I want to run that bash command om muliple server s. I stored server names in server.txt.Using for loop,script should run ssh and execute that command.

Comment: do you want output of that commands

Comment: Yes, output should be redirected to a file as in the bash command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want output of your command running by subprocess then only when command run successfully without any error then do this

```
command = subprocess.Popen ('command', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

ans,err = command.communicate()
subprocess.Popen('kill '+str(command.pid),shell=True)
```

If you want to get output of your command by complete execution without error or when your timeout expired then do this

```
command = subprocess.Popen ("command", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
command.stdin.write ("input for your command") // optional 
command.stdin.close ()
timeout = 4 // some timeout
ans,time_out = getO(command,timeout)



def getO(command,timeout):  
    poll_obj = select.poll()
    poll_obj.register(command.stdout, select.POLLIN)
    buflimit = 512000 // set as Ideal buffer limit
    idealbuffer = 1
    buf = 0
    ans =''
    start = time.time()

    while buf <= buflimit and start + timeout > time.time() : 
        poll_result = poll_obj.poll(0)
        if poll_result:
            ans+= command.stdout.read(idealbuffer)
            buf+=idealbuffer

    return ans
```